# Regex to replace spaces in quoted strings with _ (Sublime)

Tags: json, regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am trying to modify keys in my JSON file (around 60 MB) by removing spaces if there are any. I use Sublime Text Editor to load and edit large JSONs.

Currently, I am using the following expression to find quoted strings with spaces:

```
"([a-zA-Z])+([\s])+([a-zA-Z]*)":
```

**Finds**: "First Name":

Then I use the following expression to replace space with underscore with the matched string:

```
"$1_$3":
```

**Result**: "t_Name":

**Expected**: "First_Name":

I am not able to figure out why I am not able to capture the first word with $1.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Note**: There are around 15000 different keys with spaces in the JSON.

Comment: `([a-zA-Z])+` and `([\s])+` are repeated capturing groups. They only store the last char after each of these patterns finish matching. Just move the quantifiers into the groups, ``([a-zA-Z]+)`` and `\s+`.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the help @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
"([a-zA-Z]+)\s+([a-zA-Z]*)":
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/lESvwz/2/)

**Explanation**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]*                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                             (0 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ":                       '":'
```

Comment: @ak2492 You replace with `$1_$2`?  As in https://regex101.com/r/lESvwz/2/?